# In Windows 8+, how do I bring Window Desktop App to foreground when Metro App in foreground via API?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, window, setforegroundwindow

My desktop application hook some hot keys eg: CTRL+SHIFT+F12, while the hot keys are pressed, it will bring my desktop application window into foreground or stay on top. But in Window 8 or 8.1, while it is in Window Start Screen or Metro App is running in foreground, my program unable to switch back to desktop mode and bring my window into foreground. I have tried the following API,
    SetFocus(hwnd);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    SwitchToThisWindow(hwnd);

I even try on ShellExecute on "explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}", it doesn't work.

I'm not sure how Classic Shell latest version (http://www.classicshell.net) able to do this, when I pressed SHIFT+WIN key, it able to switch from Metro Mode back to desktop mode and show the Classic Shell Window.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how classic shell does it either because it's not supposed to be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set a [User Model ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378459(v=vs.85).aspx) to your application and use some of the newer APIs to bring it in focus when the user is in "Metro". Here are some code fragments in C++ to illustrate:

**Somewhere shared:**

```
const wchar_t MY_APP_USER_MODEL_ID[] = L"CompanyName.ProductSuite.AppName";
```

**In your "desktop" application startup:**

```
HRESULT hr = SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(const_cast<PWSTR>(MY_APP_USER_MODEL_ID));
// Check that SUCCEEDED(hr)
```

**In your bring-into-focus-code:**

```
IApplicationActivationManager* appMgr = nullptr;
if(SUCCEEDED(::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&appMgr)))) {
  DWORD pid = 0;
  appMgr->ActivateApplication(MY_APP_USER_MODEL_ID, nullptr, AO_NOERRORUI, &pid);
  appMgr->Release();
}
```

**Your shortcut:**

Microsoft introduce some other goofy rules tied to all of this as well. You *may* have to add some additional information to your application's shortcut **and** have that shortcut pinned to the start menu for all of this to work (no, seriously). If you find this to be the case, here is a bit of code for updating your shortcut and adding the Model ID:

```
// Assuming you already have a valid IShellLink to work with
ComPtr<IPropertyStore> propertyStore;
if(SUCCEEDED(shellLink.As(&propertyStore))) {
  PROPVARIANT appIdPropVar;
  if(SUCCEEDED(::InitPropVariantFromString(MY_APP_USER_MODEL_ID, &appIdPropVar))) {
    if(SUCCEEDED(propertyStore->SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, appIdPropVar)) &&
      SUCCEEDED(propertyStore->Commit()))
    {
     // go on to save your link/shortcut to disk...
    }
  }
}
```